# How can I search for all accounts that are suspended on a specific site?

Tags: support, search, user-accounts, account-suspension

How do I search for all accounts that are currently suspended on a specific SE site?

What I have in mind is something in analogy to typing closed:1 into the on site search text field, which results in a list of all closed questions.

Does something like this exist to find all accounts that are currently suspended on a site?

I tried **user:supended=1** on a site where I know at least one user who is currently suspended, but obtained a null result that is obviously not true ...

Comment: In short: you can't. You shouldn't.

Comment: I assume this is just available to mods using some of their tools

Comment: @ShadowWizard why?

Comment: See the answers.

Comment: Why would you ever need to know that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Stack Overflow does not advertise suspensions. It may point out that a user is suspended, but it is not going to draw attention to the fact. Suspension is about cooling down, not about public shaming.

The only way to find this is to use a search engine and look for "This account is temporarily suspended". You won't find it via any mechanism *inside* the Stack Exchange network.
Even using a search engine doesn't seem to help much here (just tried it), so there's a good chance that the Stack Exchange sites are set up to not disclose suspensions to web crawlers.

Comment: Thanks, your hint seems to work. For example when typing _"This account is temporarily suspended" site:mathematics.stackexchange.com_ into Google it some kind of does the job for the maths site.

Answer (score 4):

Since the focus of Stack Exchange sites is on the questions and their answers, I would not expect a function like this to be (or be made) available.

Moderators and automated processes only suspend in severe circumstances and the intention is for that to happen as quietly as possible so that any users involved feel comfortable returning to the sites once they been shown what was considered astray in their posts.